# Equate $e^{-i|Ψ⟩⟨Ψ|Δt}e^{-i|x⟩⟨x|Δt}$ to $(\cos^2Δt/2-\sin^2Δt/2ψ.z)I\\-2i\sinΔt/2[\cosΔt/2\frac{ψ+z}{2}+\sinΔt/2\frac{ψ\times z}{2}].\vec{σ}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, trigonometry, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

In my reference, [Page 259, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) it is given that

> Given the unitary operator $U(\Delta t)\equiv \exp(-i|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Delta t)\exp(-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t)$ where $|x\rangle\langle x|=\dfrac{I+Z}{2}=\dfrac{I+\hat{z}.\vec{\sigma}}{2}$ where $\hat{z}=(0,0,1)$, and $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\dfrac{I+\vec{\psi.\vec{\sigma}}}{2}$ where $\vec{\psi}=(2\alpha\beta,0,\alpha^2-\beta^2)$

> Here $X,Y,Z$ are Pauli matrices with $\vec{\sigma}=(X,Y,Z)$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are real numbers, and we can also prove that $\exp(-i|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Delta t)=e^{-i\Delta t}|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ and $\exp(-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t)=e^{-i\Delta t}|x\rangle\langle x|$, please refer to [Hamiltonian Simulation Circuit for Grover's Search](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/hamiltonian-simulation-circuit-for-grovers-search).

> How do we obtain the expression
> $$U(\Delta t)=\Big(\cos^2(\Delta t/2)-\sin^2(\Delta t/2)\vec{\psi}.\hat{z}\Big)I\\-2i\sin(\Delta t/2)\bigg[\cos(\Delta t/2)\dfrac{\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}}{2}+\sin(\Delta t/2)\dfrac{\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}}{2}\bigg].\vec{\sigma}$$
> up to an unimportant global phase factor ?

Note: This is the Final Expression for the Unitary Operator for Grover's Search Hamiltonian Simulation

---

**My Attempt**

$$
U(\Delta t)=\exp(-i|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Delta t).\exp(-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t)=e^{-i\Delta t}|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|.e^{-i\Delta t}|x\rangle\langle x|\\
=e^{-i\Delta t}.e^{-i\Delta t}(\dfrac{I+\vec{\psi}.\vec{\sigma}}{2})(\dfrac{I+\hat{z}.\vec{\sigma}}{2})=\frac{e^{-i\Delta t}}{2}\big(\cos(\Delta t)-i\sin(\Delta t)\big).\frac{1}{2}.\Big(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+(\vec{\psi}.\vec{\sigma})(\hat{z}.\vec{\sigma})\Big)\\
$$
Making use of the identity $(\vec{a}.\vec{\sigma})(\vec{b}.\vec{\sigma})=(\vec{a}.\vec{b})I+i(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).\vec{\sigma}$
$$
=\frac{e^{-i\Delta t}}{2}\big(\cos(\Delta t)-i\sin(\Delta t)\big).\frac{1}{2}.\Big(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\Big)\\
=\frac{e^{-i\Delta t}}{4}.\bigg[\color{red}{\cos(\Delta t)I-i\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+\cos(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+\cos(\Delta t)i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}-i\sin(\Delta t)I\\+\cos(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+-i\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I-i\sin(\Delta t).i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\bigg]\\
=\frac{e^{-i\Delta t}}{4}.\bigg[\color{red}{(2\cos^2(\Delta t/2)-1)I-i2\sin(\Delta t/2)\cos(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\+(1-2\sin^2(\Delta t/2))(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(1-2\sin^2(\Delta t/2))(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}-i\sin(\Delta t)I+\cos(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\-i\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\bigg]\\
$$
$$
=\frac{e^{-i\Delta t}}{4}.\bigg[\color{red}{2\cos^2(\Delta t/2)I}-I\color{red}{-2i\sin(\Delta t/2)\cos(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}\\+\vec{\psi}.\hat{z}I\color{red}{-2\sin^2(\Delta t/2)\vec{\psi}.\hat{z}}I\color{red}{-2i\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}+(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}-i\sin(\Delta t)I+\cos(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\-i\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\bigg]\\
=\frac{e^{-i\Delta t}}{4}.\bigg[\color{red}{2\cos^2(\Delta t/2)I}\color{red}{-2i\sin(\Delta t/2)\cos(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}\\\color{red}{-2\sin^2(\Delta t/2)\vec{\psi}.\hat{z}I}\color{red}{-2i\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}-I+\vec{\psi}.\hat{z}I+(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}-i\sin(\Delta t)I+\cos(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\-i\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+\sin(\Delta t)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\bigg]\\
$$

The red coloured terms constitute that of the required expression, but how do I deal with the rest of the terms ?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Shaun okay I have edited the post eliminating the picture.

Comment: Thank you. (I have already upvoted.)

Comment: @Shaun Could you please comment on the actual problem in my attempt ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I'm sorry. It's just not my area.

Comment: @Shaun Okay thanks. I managed to fix it and posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the calculation of $\exp(-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t)$.

$$
(|x\rangle\langle x|)^{2m}=|x\rangle\langle x|=(|x\rangle\langle x|)^{2m+1}\\
$$
\begin{align}
&e^{-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(-i\Delta t)^k(|x\rangle\langle x|)^k\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2m)!}(-i\Delta t)^{2m}(|x\rangle\langle x|)^{2m}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}(-i\Delta t)^{2m+1}(|x\rangle\langle x|)^{2m+1}\\
&=I+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-i)^{2m}}{(2m)!}(\Delta t)^{2m}.|x\rangle\langle x|-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{i(-i)^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}(\Delta t)^{2m+1}.|x\rangle\langle x|\\
&=I+|x\rangle\langle x|(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-i)^{2m}}{(2m)!}(\Delta t)^{2m}+1-1)-|x\rangle\langle x|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{i(-i)^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}(\Delta t)^{2m+1}\\
&=I-|x\rangle\langle x|+|x\rangle\langle x|\bigg(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m)!}(\Delta t)^{2m}-i\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}(\Delta t)^{2m+1}\bigg)\\
&=I+|x\rangle\langle x|\Big(\cos(\Delta t)-i\sin(\Delta t)-1\Big)=I+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)|x\rangle\langle x|
\end{align}

Therefore,

$\boxed{e^{-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t}=I+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)|x\rangle\langle x|\quad\&\quad e^{-i|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Delta t}=I+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|}$

\begin{align}
&U(\Delta t)=\exp(-i|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Delta t).\exp(-i|x\rangle\langle x|\Delta t)\\
&=(I+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|)(I+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)|x\rangle\langle x|)\\
&=I+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)(|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|+|x\rangle\langle x|)+(e^{-i\Delta t}-1)^2|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|x\rangle\langle x|\\
&=I-(1-e^{-i\Delta t})(|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|+|x\rangle\langle x|)+(1-e^{-i\Delta t})^2|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|x\rangle\langle x|\\
&=I-(2\sin^2\Delta /2+i2\sin\Delta t/2\cos\Delta t/2)(|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|+|x\rangle\langle x|)+(2\sin^2\Delta 2+i2\sin\Delta t/2\cos\Delta t/2)^2|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|x\rangle\langle x|\\
&=I-{2i}\sin\Delta t/2(\cos\Delta t/2-i\sin\Delta /2)(|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|+|x\rangle\langle x|)\\
&\quad -4\sin^2\Delta t/2(\cos\Delta t/2-i\sin\Delta /2)^2|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|x\rangle\langle x|\\
&=I-2i\sin\Delta t/2(\cos\Delta t/2-i\sin\Delta t/2)(I+\frac{(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma})}{2}\\
&\quad -4\sin^2\Delta t/2(\cos\Delta t/2-i\sin\Delta t/2)^2\frac{1}{4}(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+(\vec{\psi}.\vec{\sigma})(\hat{z}.\vec{\sigma}))\\\\
&\text{Making use of the identity} (\vec{a}.\vec{\sigma})(\vec{b}.\vec{\sigma})=(\vec{a}.\vec{b})I+i(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).\vec{\sigma}\\\\
&=I-2i\sin\Delta t/2(\cos\Delta t/2-i\sin\Delta t/2)(I+\frac{(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}{2})\\
&\quad -\sin^2\Delta t/2(\cos\Delta t/2-i\sin\Delta t/2)^2(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma})\\
&=I-2i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{-i\Delta t/2}(I+\frac{(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}{2})-\sin^2\Delta t/2.e^{-i\Delta t}(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\
&\quad +(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma})\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[e^{i
\Delta t}I-2i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}(I+\frac{(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}{2})-\sin^2\Delta t/2(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\
&\quad+(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma})]\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[(\cos\Delta t/2+i\sin\Delta t/2)e^{i\Delta t/2}I-2i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}I-i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\
&\quad -\sin^2\Delta t/2(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma})]\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[\cos\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}I-i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}I-i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\
&\quad -\sin^2\Delta t/2(I+(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I+i(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma})]\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[e^{i\Delta t/2}.e^{-i\Delta t/2}I-i\sin\Delta t/2.e^{i\Delta t/2}(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}-\sin^2\Delta t/2I\\
&\quad -\sin^2\Delta t/2(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}-\sin^2\Delta t/2(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I-i\sin^2\Delta t/2(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}]\\
\\
&\text{Substituting } \sin^2\Delta t/2=1-\cos^2\Delta t/2\text{,}\\
\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[I-i\sin\Delta t/2.(\cos\Delta t/2+i\sin\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}-(1-\cos^2\Delta t/2)I\\
&\quad -\sin^2\Delta t/2(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}-\sin^2\Delta t/2(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I-i\sin^2\Delta t/2(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}]\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[I-i\sin(\Delta t/2).\cos(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\color{blue}{+\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}-I+\cos^2(\Delta t/2)I\\
&\quad \color{blue}{-\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}}-\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I-i\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}]\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[-i\sin(\Delta t/2).\cos(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}+\cos^2(\Delta t/2)I-\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I\\
&\quad -i\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}]\\\\
&\text{Rearranging the terms,}\\\\
&=e^{-i\Delta t}[\cos^2(\Delta t/2)I-\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})I-i\sin(\Delta t/2).\cos(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}\\
&\quad -i\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z}).\vec{\sigma}]\\
&\color{red}{=e^{-i\Delta t}\bigg[\Big(\cos^2(\Delta t/2)-\sin^2(\Delta t/2)(\vec{\psi}.\hat{z})\Big)I}\\
&\quad \quad \quad \quad \color{red}{-2i\sin(\Delta t/2)\Big(\cos(\Delta t/2)\frac{(\vec{\psi}+\hat{z})}{2}+\sin(\Delta t/2)\frac{(\vec{\psi}\times\hat{z})}{2}\Big).\vec{\sigma}\bigg]}\\
\end{align}